# Is there a best-practice method for getting this day last year in python?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

For instance, today is a Wednesday. If I wanted to get this specific Wednesday last year, the method I am using so far is to create a ISOCalendar tuple from today's date and subtract one year. Is this the best way to do this, or am I missing something simple in the datetime class to be able to better get comparable dates. I do not want to get the specific date, but the specific day of the week in that specific week.

I also do not know how to correctly account for leap days.

Comment: "this specific Wednesday last year" - This specific Wednesday didn't exist last year because years aren't divided exactly by weeks. Do you want the 3rd day of the 8th week? Something like here https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2020 ?

Comment: …or the Wednesday of the 3rd week of February?

Comment: I need to be able to compare weeks to weeks. For instance I have a payweek that starts on sunday and ends on saturday, and a want to get a comparable week from last year.

Comment: So the Wednesday of the 3rd week of February is closer to what I am looking for.